# parsererror source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is how to fix this error

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, bsc

I am new to this and was able to successfully compile and deploy a token onto the BSC mainnet using the following code [image: it was successful and launched] but now I am trying to make some adjustments and re deploy but now I am not even seeing the contract at all under the "deployed contract" tab. When trying to compile the exact same code that launched successfully before I am getting this error code [image: here] and I have tried solving by changing the complier version to a number of different things but it worked once, and now isnt working again. [image]

Comment: As I can see from errror;  the contract your imported required solidity version to be less than 0.8.0 and you are using 0.8.1. However I checked latest code from zeplin and they are at `pragma solidity ^0.8.0`